# Why is sizeof() used in the argument to malloc()?

Tags: c, memory

Like this is what the book showed me
`int *list = malloc(3 * sizeof(int))`

But what's wrong with this?
`int *list = malloc(3)`

My understanding says that malloc accepts "size" as a parameter and my goal is to only let pointer `list` to accept 3 values in it, but then why would I include `sizeof(int)` when using malloc?

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to assign a 3 sized to an int"?

Comment: @cocomac allocating size of 3 to an int variable, or like I want the int variable to only accept 3 values in it.

Comment: The argument to malloc is the number of bytes you are allocating.

Comment: Thanks @cocomac I've edited the description as well as an attempt to make my question clearer.

Comment: because 3 is not 12 and not 24

Comment: `malloc`'s argument is a number of *bytes*.  It has no way of knowing that you want to allocate 3 `int`s or 3 `double`s or 3 `char`s.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to read the documentation about the functions you use. A very good website to do it is https://en.cppreference.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's look at this line of code:

```c
int *list = malloc(3 * sizeof(int))
```

It creates a pointer to an `int`, and allocated three times the size of an int worth of memory for it. So we have enough room to store three `int`s in that block of memory.

I'll assume one int takes up four bytes of memory. So to store three of them, we need 12 bytes of memory (four bytes per int times three `int`s). `malloc` allocates space in bytes, so that will give you 12 bytes of memory (`sizeof(int)` will return four as there are four bytes per int*).

Now let's look at the other version:

```c
int *list = malloc(3)
```

You allocate three bytes of memory. Sadly, one int is four bytes... so you have enough space for 3/4 of an int (again, assuming one int is four bytes). If you wanted to store three ints, you need to allocate memory equal to three times however big an int is, hence `3 * sizeof(int)`.

---

*Technically, there are platforms where an `int` isn't four bytes. So it is better to write `sizeof(int)` instead of `4`. Don't worry about that for now, though.

Comment: Re "*there are platforms where an int isn't four bytes.*", Indeed, it can be 1, 2, 4, 8, anything. As long it can store -32,767..32,767, and as long as it's at least as large as a `short`.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter to malloc() is the number of bytes you want to allocate.

`int* list = malloc(3)` will only allocate 3 bytes

Each integer on a 32-bit platform is 32 bits (4 bytes). This can be obtained with `sizeof(int)`

An array of 3 integers will take `3*sizeof(int)` which is 12 bytes on a 32-bit platform.

So

```c
int* list = malloc(3*sizeof(int))
```

will allocate the space for 3 integers, which is 12 bytes on a 32-bit platform